# Ordering OpenCv contours in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv, contour

I have found contours out of a binary image with findContours, putting them in a 2d vector.This is what i've done:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(image,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Now i want to sort them from biggest to smaller:how can i handle this?
Thanks all!

Comment: In accordance to which parameter do you want to sort them?

Comment: I want to sort them in accordance to length.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to use [cvContourArea](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_StructAnalysis.htm#decl_cvContourArea) to calculate area of each contour and then sort them using any [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Good luck!

Comment: Anyway there's no better way to do this?in old OpenCV i could have been sorting the Seq of contours with cvSeqSort:there's no similar function for OpenCV 2?

Comment: @Idima sorry, I haven't found this.

Comment: ok thanks!Anyway I've found also arcLength to get the length of the contour while looking doc for contourArea,so thanks for made me look at that ;)